# Spring Data Rest - Saving a resource with associated resources

Tags: angularjs, spring-data-rest

The following works fine:

```
new Post({

    content : newPost.content,
    poster : poster._links.self.href,
    timeline : "http://localhost:8080/users/" + timelineUserId

}).$save(function(post) {

    $scope.timeline.push(post); 

});
```

But what I want to do is:

```
new Post({

    content : newPost.content,
    poster : poster,
    timeline : "http://localhost:8080/users/" + timelineUserId

}).$save(function(post) {

    $scope.timeline.push(post); 

});
```

So that I have a populated poster in the callback of save instead of having a URI. But the server returns:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: project.domain.Post["poster"]);
```

Is there a way to make this work or should I save it as in first example and retrieve it back from server right after and try to populate the poster there?

Comment: `poster` is **not** a nested resource, it's a resource on its own.

Comment: What makes you say so? Isn't it both?